# Why is taskkill hanging when called from c# code?

Tags: c#, unmanaged, taskkill

Taskkill is (ironically) hanging when I call it from a c# library to clear WerFault.exe processes

I'm trying to use taskkill to close WerFault processes that are spawned duriung a load test running from nunit. The WerFault.exe is created whenever an external process that is launched by the test fails, either because it can't connect to the service its using, or because it runs out of memory. Temporarily ecuse the fact that this is quite a convoluted way of putting load into a system, and I'd rather be interacting with the service I'm putting load into directly, this is a means to an end for the time being and not a long term solution.

The processes are unmanaged c++ exes so I can't use Process.GetProcessesByName(processName) and then process.kill on the result.

I've put a potential fix in the sample below, but I won't be able to test this until later as i need to run a lot of iterations to force the WerFault.exe. any suggestions welcome!

Here's what I got so far:-

processName.KillProcessesByName(true);

```
    public static void KillProcessesByName(this string processname, bool useCommandLine)
    {
        if (useCommandLine)
        {
            using (var cmd = new ProcessRunner(new ProcessStartInfoWrapper
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            }))
            {
                string format = string.Format("cmd.exe /k \"taskkill /F /T /IM \"\"{0}\"\"\"", processname);

// string format = string.Format("taskkill /F /T /IM \"{0}\"", processname); // leaves taskkill hanging
                Console.WriteLine(format);
                cmd.SendInput(format);
                //format = string.Format("taskkill /F /T /IM \"taskkill\"");
                //cmd.SendInput(format);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            processname.KillProcessesByName();
        }
    }
```

Here's the Process runner class:-

```
public class ProcessRunner : IProcessRunner
{
    private readonly IList<string> _standardErrorOutputList;
    private readonly IList<string> _standardOutputList;
    bool _disposed;

    public ProcessRunner(IProcessStartInfoWrapper processStartInfoWrapper)
    {
        ProcessStartInfoWrapper = processStartInfoWrapper;
        ProcessStartInfoWrapper.SetupProcessStartInfo();
        Process = new Process {StartInfo = ProcessStartInfoWrapper.ProcessStartInfo};
        NewProcessStarted = Process.Start();
        if (ProcessStartInfoWrapper.RedirectStandardOutput)
        {
            _standardOutputList = new List<string>();
            Process.OutputDataReceived += StandardOutputHandler;
            Process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }
        if (ProcessStartInfoWrapper.RedirectStandardError)
        {
            _standardErrorOutputList = new List<string>();
            Process.ErrorDataReceived += StandardErrorOutputHandler;
            Process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        }
        //defer assigning the process to the job until the stdOutput has been redirected so that no messages are missed
        AssignProcessToJobObject(_job, Process.Handle);
        if (ProcessStartInfoWrapper.RedirectStandardInput)
        {
            StreamWriter = Process.StandardInput;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     ToDo:- create an extension class for IProcessRunner and add this as a default implementation of
    ///     StandardOutputHandler
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void StandardOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_standardOutputList)
        {
            _standardOutputList.Add(e.Data);
        }
    }

    public void StandardErrorOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_standardErrorOutputList)
        {
            _standardErrorOutputList.Add(e.Data);
        }
    }

    public void SendInput(string input)
    {
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(input);
    }

    public void WaitForStandardOutputToContainText(string expectedText, int waitTimeMilliSeconds)
    {
        WaitForListToContainText(_standardOutputList, expectedText, waitTimeMilliSeconds);
    }

    public void WaitForStandardErrorOutputToContainText(string expectedText, int waitTimeMilliSeconds)
    {
        WaitForListToContainText(_standardErrorOutputList, expectedText, waitTimeMilliSeconds);
    }

    public IProcessStartInfoWrapper ProcessStartInfoWrapper { get; set; }
    public Process Process { get; private set; }
    public bool NewProcessStarted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     publicly returns a copy of the StandardOutputList, while locking the backing field to prevent any changes
    ///     when the copy has been returned, the lock is released, and other threads can write to the property or its backing
    ///     field
    /// </summary>
    public IList<string> StandardOutputList
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_standardOutputList)
            {
                return SetShadowList(_standardOutputList);
            }
        }
    }

    public IList<string> StandardErrorOutputList
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_standardErrorOutputList)
            {
                return SetShadowList(_standardErrorOutputList);
            }
        }
    }

    public StreamWriter StreamWriter { get; private set; }

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers. 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern. 
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Free any other managed objects here. 
            //
            //todo:- implement Log4Net
            // ReSharper disable EmptyGeneralCatchClause
            int processId = default(int);
            try
            {
                processId = Process.Id;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            try
            {
                if (ProcessStartInfoWrapper.RedirectStandardOutput)
                {
                    Process.OutputDataReceived -= StandardOutputHandler;
                    _standardOutputList.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            try
            {
                if (ProcessStartInfoWrapper.RedirectStandardError)
                {
                    Process.ErrorDataReceived -= StandardOutputHandler;
                    _standardErrorOutputList.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            try
            {
                if (ProcessStartInfoWrapper.RedirectStandardInput)
                {
                    StreamWriter.Flush();
                    StreamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            try
            {
                if (!HasExitedCheck())
                {
                    Process.CloseMainWindow();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            try
            {
                Process.Close();
                Process.WaitForExit(10000);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            try
            {
                Process.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            try
            {
                if (!HasExitedCheck())
                {
                    Process.Kill();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            Process.Dispose();
            ProcessStartInfoWrapper.Dispose();

            try
            {
                //small theoretical risk of another process starting with same id, but this does make sure unmanaged processes close!
                Process.GetProcessById(processId).Kill();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }


    private bool HasExitedCheck()
    {
        //unmanaged processes might not have .HasExited, so check here and default to false
        bool hasExited = false;
        try
        {
            hasExited = Process.HasExited;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return hasExited;
        // ReSharper restore EmptyGeneralCatchClause
    }

    private void WaitForListToContainText(IList<string> list, string expectedText, int waitTimeMilliSeconds)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= waitTimeMilliSeconds)
        {
            if (SyncOnTextInList(list, expectedText, false)) return;
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        SyncOnTextInList(list, expectedText, true);
    }

    private bool SyncOnTextInList(IList<string> list, string expectedText, bool throwExceptions)
    {
        bool sync = false;
        lock (list)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] shadowList = SetShadowList(list);
                if (shadowList.Any(line => line.Trim().Contains(expectedText.Trim())))
                    //if (shadowList.Any(line => line != null && line.Trim().Contains(expectedText.Trim())))
                {
                    sync = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (throwExceptions)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        return sync;
    }

    private static string[] SetShadowList(ICollection<string> list)
    {
        var shadowList = new string[list.Count];
        list.CopyTo(shadowList, 0);
        shadowList = shadowList.Select(x => x ?? "").ToArray();
        return shadowList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you with hanging btw? Do the proccesses get killed only after a delay?

Comment: might be a permission problem, what happens if start your program as administrator?

Comment: Why you calling `cmd` twice?

Comment: @leppie I'm calling cmd from cmd as I suspected that the cmd process I was launching directly was being killed off by the dispose call before it had managed to send the task kill instruction. I thought opening up a 2nd cmd and calling task kill from there would help, but as it happens it doesnt

Comment: Clarification , the double call to cmd.exe does work if the load on the machine running the test isn't too high. Mostly. With 500 concurrent sessions I'm left with hundreds of task kill processes, with 300 I'm left with 2 cmd.exe processes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I used the sample from 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18146/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-Proce
to handle the process killing, and found some other useful methods there for querying processes which work more reliably for unmanaged code. It's a much better way of killing a process rather than having to launch another process (or two , or three) to do the job.

So "why is taskkill hanging?", well from my experimentation it looks like its a question of load.

Just realised I could have launched taskkill directly which might have worked, rather than launching from cmd.exe, but at least I've learned how to call WMI from .Net today